# execve failed to overlay process

Tags: c, parallel-processing, execve

I am new to parallel processing and was attempting to use fork() to create a new child process where I would like to overlay this process by using execve. It happened to me that execve("_filename",array, NULL) sometimes works but most of the time, it failed to overlay the process and return -1; I tried to run other's sample code but it failed on my laptop so I am wondering if this is because of my mac's configuration? I am really new to this topic and hope I can find help here, thanks!

Here is the program I am attempting to run:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // populate arraay with random numbers
    int child_status;
    pid_t pid;
    int i;
    pid = fork();
    char *array[3] = {"Hello", "There", "Test"};

    if (pid == 0) {
        pid = execve("Process4", array, NULL);
        exit(0);
    }
    int num = -1;
    printf("What is 2 + 2");
    while (num != 4) {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        if (num == 4) {
            printf("You win                    \n");
        } else {
            printf("%i incorrect - try again ", num);
            printf("\r\b\r");
        }
    }
    wait(&child_status);
    return (0);
}
```

And for Process4, I wrote below:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int secs = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i;
    if (argc > 0) {
        printf("The arguments supplied are:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            printf("%s\t", argv[i]);
        }
    } else {
        printf("argument list is empty.\n");
    }

    int j;
    printf("\n");
    while (secs < 10) {
        printf("Time:%i\n", secs);
        fflush(0);
        sleep(1);
        secs++;
        printf("\r\b\r");
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

My process4 should be able to receive the parameters passed in (as an array in the second argument) and start the timer.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: In addition to the answer by @MikeCAT, the first element of the array should be the program name. The executed program will see it as `argv[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The array to specify the arguments for [`execve()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) must be terminated by `NULL`.

Try

```c
char *array[] = {"Hello", "There", "Test", NULL};
```

instead of

```c
char *array[3] = {"Hello", "There", "Test"};
```